# Change addresses and key backup on Bitcoin Wallet for Android

Tags: private-key, public-key, backup, change, bitcoin-wallet-app

I've had the  Bitcoin Wallet for Android for some time. When I installed it I was assigned some public address/key. I have made various transactions in and out of the wallet but as fas as I can tell the address has not changed.

Does Android Wallet not transfer change from a transaction into a new address?

I actually don’t want it to do this. I want one fixed address I can use to send and receive coins. I also expected that the private key I backed-up early on would still be valid.

If change addresses are created does this mean I have to backup my keys after every transaction?

Answer (score 1):

Android Bitcoin Wallet does not send change to a new address. You don't need to re-backup your keys unless you explicitly generate a new address.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the balance at blockchain.info/address/yourAddress. If it matches your wallet balance, then your whole balance is at the original address with the original key. If not, your wallet should be keeping track of change addresses.

You can also see the out transactions on blockchain. If they go to 2 addresses different from your main one, one is a change address.